# Problema al guardar un archivo en Python

Tags: python, csv

estoy teniendo un error al querer guardar un archivo generado de una consulta de SQL, he probado poniendo el full path tanto con \ como con \, pero al correrlo me da el error :FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Regional8-12/08/19'

```py
import cx_Oracle
import os.path
import os
import time
fecha = time.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
NumeroRegional=int(input('ingrese el numero de regional:'))
titulo=str('Regional{}-{}'.format(NumeroRegional,fecha))
con = cx_Oracle.connect('zuri/zuri@127.0.0.1:1521/XE')
cur = con.cursor()
query=str('SELECT last_name, job_id, salary FROM   employees WHERE  job_id = (SELECT job_id  FROM   employees WHERE  employee_id = 141)AND    salary >                (SELECT salary                 FROM   employees                 WHERE  employee_id = 143)')
cur.execute(query)
file = open('C:\\Users\\leand\\Desktop\\{}.txt' .format(titulo), "w+")
file.write('probando;' '\n')
file.close()
file = open('C:\\Users\\leand\\Desktop\\{}.txt' .format(titulo), "w")
for row in cur:
    file.write(row[0] + chr(9) + row[1] + chr(9) + str(row[2]) + '\n')
file.close()
cur.close()
con.close()
print(titulo)
print("File successfully exported")
```

Comment: Un par de cosas que destacar. Evita el uso de / o de \ en nombres de archivos o tendrás pesadillas. Tambien te aconsejo usar el context manager `with` para abrir y cerrar conexiones, es mucho más _pythonico_ y seguro. Por uiltimo el uso de tabulaciones hackeando el codigo ascii no es necesario en python, buscate la documentacion del modulo `format`y verás que es mucho más flexible y sencillo. Si necesitas ejemplos de eso dilo y lo miramos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando abres un archivo con open indicando `"w"` o `"w+"` como parámetro, crea el archivo si no existe, lo cual es correcto.

No obstante, ese archivo debe poder ser creado, ten en cuenta que en Windows no se pueden utilizar `/` como nombre de archivo y o bien al intentar crearlo no puede, o bien interpreta las `/` como separador de directorios.

Cambia la quinta línea por

```
fecha = time.strftime("%d.%m.%y")
```

Y no creo que te de problemas.

Comment: Mil gracias!!! funciono perfecto!

Comment: @LeandroZurita si funcionó, te agradecería mucho que marques la respuesta como correcta por si le sucede a alguien más :)